# NicEdit with jQuery Autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, richtext, nicedit

I'm trying to make a rich text editor with an autocomplete feature. Right now i'm using NicEdit to turn a textarea into a rich text editor, works ok(i'm using it for its simplicity). Also i'm using the **autocomplete** feature form jQuery successfully on textboxes or textareas, but if i try to use the same textarea that **NicEdit** uses(that is a text area with "textareaID" id), it doesn't work beacause NicEdit changes the textarea into DIVs with different IDs(in my case the html source ID for that DIV is "nicEdit-main"), and the autocomplete does not work on the DIVs ID.

So, autocomplete does not work on:

```
 $("#nicEdit-main").autocomplete({...
```

neither does on:

```
 $("#textareaID").autocomplete({...
```

An idea on how i can accomplish NicEdit and autocomplete to work on the same textarea, will be appreciated.